# Microsoft Identity with local account and mobile apps

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0, microsoft-identity-web

I created a website using NET8 and Blazor. The authentication for this website is based on `Microsoft Identity` and the users are stored in my SQL database. The website has the pages to create a user and all the other pages provided by the tool.

In companion with the website, I like to create an app using `MAUI`. At least, I like a user to create a new account and log in. I was thinking of creating the WebApi in the main Blazor project for that.

Also, the website uses an external WebAPI that is protected using Identity Server: the website calls the APIs using the tokens provided.

I have a few concerns about it:

- is there already an implementation of those APIs?
- how can I guarantee the protection of the APIs?
- can I merge the users from Microsoft Identity with the users from the Identity Server? (Microsoft Identity is based on Identity Server)